# why cant i access postgres in docker container from other container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that initializes a node container and a postgres container. Here's what that looks like:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    server:
        build: .
        command: npm start
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        environment:
            - DB_HOST=db
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        container_name: "service__db"
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
        volumes:
            - my_dbdata1:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
    my_dbdata1:
```

both containers go live and i can ssh into them and ports are available. however, I cant access the postgres container from the node container. When I log `process.env.DB_HOST` I get a literal string; `'db'`. I'm also using sequelize as an ORM and I can't get migrations to run. I dont see errors or anything, sequelize initializes and then just stops

is there something I'm missing from the compose.yml file?

I guess an important thing to mention is this is running locally on a mac

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    server:
        build: .
        command: npm start
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_HOST ='db'
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        container_name: "service__db"
        image: postgres
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
        volumes:
            - my_dbdata1:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
    my_dbdata1:
```

Comment: What have you changed?  Why does it make a difference?

Comment: I'm just following the docker hub documentation page for postgres image.https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres